# applying functions to pasted strings in R

Tags: r, function, paste

I have a dataframe,df, with many columns cola,colb etc each consisting of a sequence of integers 0 or 1

```
df$cola 
[1] 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 etc.
```

I am using the subSeq function in the doBy package to obtain some sequences
and want to apply this to all columns

I have tried putting the columns into a vector

```
cols <- colnames(df) # "cola" "colb" etc.
```

and have tried without success this approach

```
subSeq(get(paste0("df$",cols[1]))) # error object 'df$cola' not found
```

Could not easily find an equivalent on site via search

Comment: Might not have understood correctly, but if you want to apply the same function to all columns you could use `lapply(df, subSeq, ...)`, where `...` are additional arguments to `subSeq`.

Comment: Wouldn't `subSeq(df[,cols[1]])` work?

Comment: @Backlin . yes i was planning to lapply on the df when I had function correct

Comment: @JU. Thanks. I was overcomplicating the issue!

Comment: @JU. I now realize that the real world df was actually a data.table. I coerced to data.frame and that solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `df[[cols[1]]]`.

Note that `df[["foo"]]` is the same as `df$foo`.